# Vectorizing BMP file into a single, open path as opposed to a closed path object

Tags: python, opencv, svg, image-processing, scikit-learn

I'm doing a simple image processing project. It involves converting binary images into open paths (like those drawn with the pen tool on Adobe Illustrator). The issue I am running into is that the exported SVG is drawn as a closed object, not an open path.

**These are the steps I have taken so far**:

1. Input binarized image
2. Invert binarized image (Scikit)
3. Skeletonized inverted image (Scikit)
4. Convert image to 8bit
5. Export 8bit as JPG
6. Convert JPG to BMP with `pillow`
7. Convert BMP to SVG with `potrace`

**Program 1 - Binarizing, inverting, skeletonizing etc.**

```
from skimage.morphology import skeletonize
from skimage.util import invert
from skimage import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2
import numpy as np
import svgwrite

# Reading BINARY input & converting to greyscale
image = cv2.imread("C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\input2.JPG", cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
greyscale = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Threshold the grayscale image to get a binary image
_, binary_image = cv2.threshold(greyscale, 127, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Invert binary image
inversion = invert(binary_image)

# "Skeletonization"
skeleton = skeletonize(inversion)

# Convert image to 8-bit
skeleton_8bit = np.uint8(skeleton * 255)

# Increase line thickness by dilating the image
kernel = np.ones((3,3),np.uint8)
dilated_skeleton = cv2.dilate(skeleton_8bit, kernel, iterations = 1)

# Create a new SVG drawing
dwg = svgwrite.Drawing("C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\svg_output1.svg", profile='full')

# Iterate over the pixels in the dilated skeleton image
for y in range(skeleton_8bit.shape[0]):
    for x in range(skeleton_8bit.shape[1]):
        # If the pixel is white, add a line to the SVG
        if skeleton_8bit[y, x] > 0:
            dwg.add(dwg.line((x, y), (x+1, y), stroke=svgwrite.rgb(0, 0, 0, '%')))

# Save the SVG
dwg.save()

# Writing the image to a file
cv2.imwrite("C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\skeleton_output1.JPG", skeleton_8bit)
```

**Program 2 - Converting JPG to BMP**

```
from PIL import Image

# Open the JPG image
image = Image.open('C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\output7.JPG')

# Save the image as a BMP file
image.save('C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\bitmap_output1.bmp')
```

**Program 3 - Converting BMP to SVG**

```
import subprocess

# Define the Potrace command as a list of strings
command = ["potrace", "-s", "-o", "C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\vectorized_output1.svg", "C:\\Users\\jackc\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\medial_skeleton\\bitmap_output1.bmp"]

# Run the command
subprocess.run(command, check=True)
```

--

Input image:
[Input for **Program 1**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lt9Y.jpg)

The issue I am running into now is that the exported SVG isn't a single path made up of a line of control points, but an object, composed of a closed path. See image below:

[Closed path object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQPxM.png)

My desired outcome is a single path, made up of a line of single control points. This example was by processing the binarized input image, and using Adobe Illustrator's "line art" image trace feature. See image below:

[Single line, open path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MpWFm.png)

How to achieve this?

**Update: achieved this with the AutoTrace library (https://github.com/autotrace/autotrace) centerline function.**

Comment: Your code and your description disagree on what program 1 does. Your description claims it write a JPG, your code shows you creating an SVG file, which you then _convert_ to a JPG, so: throw some `imshow` instructions in between your lines and see at what point things stop doing what you expected them to. Then you can focus your post on asking specifically about that part, with all the preamble and followup removed (because those simply aren't necessary for a [mcve])

Comment: Not familar with Scikit. Ideally you: 1. skeletonize from a raster image 2. retrieve polyline point data from this process 3.  use the point array to draw a svg polyline element. Rendering the skeletonized data to another raster image is superfluous and can't work as a basis for vectorizers like potrace - as these tools always try to return closed shapes. In other words:  skeletonizing and bitmap tracing are two very different kinds of vectorization.  You need only the skeleton-flavor  and admittedly some manual work to create the svg. See also: https://github.com/LingDong-/skeleton-tracing